# Can I induct on the positive natural numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, induction, natural-numbers

I started reading Terry Tao's [Analysis I](https://lms.umb.sk/pluginfile.php/111477/mod_page/content/5/TerenceTao_Analysis.I.Third.Edition.pdf) and am trying to do the second exercise in the text which is to prove

> **Lemma 2.2.10.** Let $a$ be a positive number. Then there exists exactly
> one natural number $b$ such that $b++ = a$.

The exercise gives the hint to use induction. This seems easy: just prove the case for $a=1$, then use induction on $a$ to prove true for all positive numbers. But in the text the axiom of induction is presented such that induction on $0$ proves for all natural numbers.

> **Axiom 2.5** (Principle of mathematical induction). Let $P(n)$ be any
> property pertaining to a natural number $n$. Suppose that $P(0)$ is true,
> and suppose that whenever $P(n)$ is true, $P(n++)$ is also true. Then
> $P(n$) is true for every natural number $n$.

How do I know/prove I can do induction starting at $1$ to prove for all positive natural numbers?

Comment: Make the statement $P(n)$ be "either $n=0$ or else `blah`". You'll have to prove that $n=1$ case separately (that is, do two "bases"), but the $n=0$ case is trivial.

Comment: Given a property $P$, consider the new property $Q(n)\equiv P(n+1)$. If you want $P$ to hold starting at $1$, that's the same as having $Q$ hold starting at $0$. (And this trick similarly lets you start at any integer.)

Comment: Thanks. I just realized another way to put it would be "if $n$ is positive..." which will be automatically true for $0$

Comment: You can do induction starting *anywhere*.  A base case is nothing more or less than the first case it is true.  ....  Math is *thinking*.  Not doing magical incantations.  Don't get hung up on magical ingredients.... I maybe I should say .. the ingredients aren't magic.  The ingredients are a frame of reference-- they provide you with a method to filter vague idea to pure reason; but they *don't* lock you into religious dogma.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah. I certainly knew that I could just start at 1, but Tao's book and his proofs seem to focus on great amounts of rigor, and the fact that starting at 1 reaches all positive numbers shouldn't be used without proving it, even if it seems obvious.

Comment: Actually I worried about the rigor and about my editorial opinion and maybe I was wrong in it. Obviously we need rigor and we *can't* say... "well obviously".  And although getting to all naturals but taking successors is "obvious" we are only allowed it because of an axiom. And the axiom starts at $0$.  Also my "just start anywhere" really applies to more advanced statements.  A statement such as "every natural number has exactly on predessor" is so basic I probably shouldn't have been so glib.

Comment: ... Actually... I'm almost ready to do a 180 on my comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do induction starting *anywhere*.

A base case is nothing more or less than the first case it is true.  ....  Math is *thinking*.  Not doing magical incantations.  Don't get hung up on magical ingredients.... I maybe I should say .. the ingredients aren't magic.  The ingredients are a frame of reference-- they provide you with a method to filter vague idea to pure reason; but they *don't* lock you into religious dogma.

But .... if you want to figure out how to *use* religious dogma.   If you want to do induction starting at a base case of say, $27$.  That is $P(n)$ is true for all natural numbers $n \ge 27$ you can simple state:  Let $Q(m)$ be the statement "$P(m+27)$ is true".  Doing induction on $Q(m)$ starting at $0$ will be *exactly* the same thing as doing induction on $P(n)$ starting at $27$.

*AND* the induction needn't have a step of only the *next* number.

If I wanted to prove something is true for every *third* natural number after $25$ (that is it is true for $25, 28,31$ but not for $26,27, 29,30$ etc, I can do induction starting at $25$ and do an induction step that $P(n)\implies P(n+3)$.

ANd the magical incantation?  "Let $Q(n)$ be the statement 'P(25 + 3n) is true'".  Then doing induction on $P$ starting at $25$ and only on every third number is the exact same thing as doing induction on $Q$ starting at $0$ and proving for each successor.

You can even do induction going in a negative direction.

=========

Okay.... I'm doing a *complete* 180 and when comes to basic *defining* you systems from the very beginning.  *Those* steps need to be rigourous.  And here we are defining the natural numbers so it must be rigorous.

I think we need to be careful in our basic statement.

> $P(n)$ be the statement *if $n \ne 0$* then there is a unique $a$ so that $a++ =n$.

Basic case:  $P(0)$ is vacuously true.

But now our *induction* step is going to be strange and nearly pure bootstrap.

Suppose $P(n)$.   Consider $n++$.  Let $a = n$. Then $n++ = a++$ so there does exist a natural $a$ so that $a++ = n++$.  Now we just have to show there is no other.  But if $b \ne a$ is a natural number then axiom 2.4 says $b++ \ne a++ = n++$.  So $a$ is unique.

....

Now, I'll admit that barely seems to be *induction*.  Can't we just use 2.4 on $n$ directly?  Well..... How do we know that there exists *any* $a$ so that $a++ = n$?

Well, here's a weird and subtle thing about induction.  We know we can start an numbers system with $0$ and for every $n$ we have $n++$ exists.  And $1 =0++$. But how do we know that there isn't any $n: 0 < n < 1$ (assuming we have defined $"<"$) or that there is no $m: n < m < n++$

We'll induction say if something is true for if something is true for $n$ implies it is true for $n++$ (and it is true for $0$) then it is true for *all* natural numbers.  This doesn't just mean we can bootstrap all the natural numbers by taking successors.  It means that if we *do* do that we create *all* the natural number by doing so and there aren't any natural numbers that *aren't* created this way.

Okay... when I type it out it doesn't sound all that astonishing but think of it.  How do we prove that all the numbers we create by doing $0,0++=1; 1++=2$, etc are all and we can't sneek in a number between $2$ and $3$.  $0$ is created that way.  And if $n$ is so is $n++$.  So all natural numbers, by axiom, are and by axiom we can't sneek any in.